# Where to find my tables on DB2

Tags: db2, ibm-data-studio

I have created a table, but is not listed on DataStudio 4101(tables node)

I can insert data by sql commands and drop/create the table, but can not find it on the server Database Node, under tables.

Other tables are displayed, but not the new ones I made.

Comment: Are you looking in the right schema? If you just created it without a schema identifier, it will automatically be created in a schema matching the username you're logging in with.  I think you want `Connection -> Database -> Schemas -> your_schema -> Tables`

Comment: i am in my Schema as you say.

Comment: i can find the UDT and UDF, but not the tables...

Comment: Which type of OS is your DB2 server running on?  IBM i (fka OS/400), Linux/Unix/Windows, or z/OS?

Comment: I try windows 8 and open suse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are using DB2 for i, with "system naming" mode, then your tables may have been created in schema QGPL (the General Purpose Library) by default.  Your DB2 session would find them by using its "library list", similar to a path list.